# managed mbcs to wide

Tags: c#

I have a byte array of MBCS characters to convert to Unicode wide characters.  Any help?
This doesn't work.

```
var encoder = new UnicodeEncoding();

while (true)
{
    int bytesRead = fstream.Read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);

    //could not read from file stream
    if (bytesRead == 0)
        break;

    Console.Write(encoder.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead));
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "MBCS" (multi-byte character set)? There are lots of different MBCS implementations (UTF-7,UTF-8,UTF-16,Shift-JIS,...) for instance).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use Encoding.Convert(srcEncoding, dstEncoding, ...) to do this.

Comment: Why isn't there a UTF16 encoding?